# How do I add a mouse listener to all open editors?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to write a view plugin that, when opened, will cycle through all the currently open editors and add a mouse listener to each. I know I can get all the editors by using something like:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences()
```

However, I'm at a loss as to how add the listener. From the editor reference I can get the editor part, but I don't know how to get the underlying control to which I would add my mouse listener. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors may have lots of controls, so there is no one control you could add your listener to.

You can add a listener that is called from **everything** in the application using `Display.addFilter`, something like:

```
Display display = Display.getDefault();

display.addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
```

Comment: Turns out I was working inside a large legacy framework that had hooks for what I needed to do, so the question became irrelevant for me, but I will mark this as the answer because a question should have an accepted answer, IMHO.